# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'React')

Tags: reactjs

I have an app that works well locally. But on production, I am getting this error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/im8O0.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYuJa.png)

I thought it is related to webpack but could not find any clue. I am stuck with that.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import moment from 'moment';
import * as styled from 'styled-components';
import NotificationContext from 'og-merchant-portal-react-library/lib/NotificationContext/NotificationContext';
import FetchContext from 'og-merchant-portal-react-library/lib/FetchContext';
import { UserInfoContext } from 'og-merchant-portal-react-library';

import App from './App';
import { unregister } from './serviceWorker';

window.IngenicoLib = {
    React,
    ReactDOM,
    moment,
    NotificationContext,
    FetchContext,
    UserInfoContext,
    'styled-components': styled,
};
```

Comment: You need to show some sample code.

Comment: Your app is trying to use a React copy from `window.IngenicoLib.React`.

Comment: I found the answer. Thanks for your help